# rMaps choropleth with custom json

Tags: r, topojson, choropleth

With R I want to make an [animated choropleth map](http://rmaps.github.io/blog/posts/animated-choropleths/index.html) with the `rMaps` package  and a custom map. I tried to follow the example of Diego Valle described [here](http://lcolladotor.github.io/2014/02/26/excited-by-willingness-to-help-get-things-done/) and to use the [custom map info for Datamaps](https://github.com/markmarkoh/datamaps/blob/master/README.md#using-custom-maps).

However, ***the map does not display***. But, the legend with the proper fill key appears with the year animation bar. The topoJson file seems to be fine.

```
library(rCharts);library(rMaps);library(rgdal)
map = readOGR("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gupierre/GHA_vol/master/Data/GHA_adm/GHA_adm1.topo.json", layer="admin_1",stringsAsFactors=F)
#Data:

SDLOG<-read.table("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gupierre/GHA_vol/master/Data/sdlog.csv", header=T,stringsAsFactors=F, sep =",")
head(SDLOG)
 year          name      sdlog  type
>1 2004 Greater Accra 0.20030687 urban
>2 2005 Greater Accra 0.15322712 urban
>3 2006 Greater Accra 0.10782677 urban


#Map:

library(rCharts);library(rMaps)
d1 <- ichoropleth(sdlog ~ name, data = SDLOG[SDLOG$type=="rural",], ncuts = 7, pal = 'YlOrRd', animate = 'year',  map = 'admin_1')
d1$set(
  geographyConfig = list(
    dataUrl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gupierre/GHA_vol/master/Data/GHA_adm/GHA_adm1.topo.json"
  ),
 scope = 'admin_1',
  setProjection = '#! function( element, options ) {
  var projection, path;
  projection = d3.geo.mercator()
  .center([8, -1]).scale(element.offsetWidth)
  .translate([element.offsetWidth / 2, element.offsetHeight / 2]);

  path = d3.geo.path().projection( projection );
  return {path: path, projection: projection};
  } !#'
)
d1
```

*Note: this question was asked on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28718397/rmaps-choropleth-with-custom-map) without success. I don't know the policy on GIS for posting questions from SO. Please advise in the comments if I am wrong in simply copy pasting my initial question.*

Comment: Welcome to our site!  The preferred method is to flag your original question for *migration*: that will create automatic links between the two versions but inform people that answers should be posted here if possible.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: I'm working on it but yours url are actually broken. Could you repair those or share your files with us ?

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell what exactly are you trying to do because the url you are using as example actually doesn't show a thing. The same with your data url's.
[image]

Anyway, here you have a simplyfied code (modifying a little bit the few registers that you are showing using head()) in order to get rid of this unanswered question.

```
library(rMaps)
library(plyr)

#new path to csv
SDLOG <- read.table("csv.csv", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F, sep =",")
SDLOG <- mutate(SDLOG, state = c("UT", "NE", "AL")) #add place for plotting
head(SDLOG)
  year          name     sdlog  type state
1 2004 Greater Accra 0.2003069 urban    UT
2 2005 Greater Accra 0.1532271 urban    NE
3 2006 Greater Accra 0.1078268 urban    AL
4 2004 Greater Accra 0.1555555 urban    UT
5 2007 Greater Accra 0.3000000 urban    NE
6 2005 Greater Accra 0.2500000 urban    AL

#Map:
d1 <- ichoropleth(sdlog ~ state,
                  data = SDLOG[SDLOG$type=="urban",],
                  ncuts = 7,
                  pal = 'YlOrRd',
                  animate = 'year')

d1
```

[image]